# Recording direct from camera into MacBook Pro via HDMI?

Tags: video, camera, hdmi, video-editing, video-adapter

Is there any way to 'tether' my camera via its HDMI out to a MacBook pro?

The goal is to record live, uncompressed, video direct from a camera. Thus skipping the camera's file system and recording directly onto the Mac's hard drive via Premier Pro or similar software.

Comment: HDMI is an output structure, not two-way, so… no.

Comment: Capturing HDMI output via HDMI is possible. People are doing it, but what is the easiest way via MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MacBook Pro HDMI port is output only.

So no, you can not use it as input for your recording.

Your alternatives are USB 3 or Thunderbolt.

Comment: Ah, ok. But the camera does have a mini-HDMI out. So HDMI to Thunderbolt?

Comment: your next step will depend on what camera you have. I just clarified that you can not use the HDMI-port as input on your Macbook. If you have additional question do not hesitate to ask. The camera HDMI output on your camcorder is for viewing on TV or Monitors (with HDMI input).

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works for me `camera's HDMI -> Mac's USB` but it requires a special device:

- I have a Panasonic HC-V777 camera which has a micro HDMI output (the micro HDMI - HDMI cabel is provided with the camera out of the box).
- I have a Corsair Elgato HD60 S capture device which has 2 HDMIs: input and output. Also it provides an output port and a cable that connects HD60 to my Macbook's USB.
- I connect my camera to HD60 which connects the camera to the USB.
- OBS Studio is software that works on macOS and is HD60-friendly: it supports a special adapter that makes it possible to both record and stream the input from the camera coming to HD60 from the camera's micro HDMI.

The disadvantage of this approach is the need in the extra device (HD60 S) and also this device requires output to go somewhere otherwise the capture does not work. I connect it to the second monitor where I see the output from my camera that is passed through the HD60.

Answer (score 0):

you need a hub that captures like USB Capture HDMI Magewell

Comment: This doesn't make sense either technically or grammatically.  What exactly are you trying to say?

Answer (score -1):

Trying to figure this out also - BUT with HDMI to Firewire...looks like I may need an additional adapter of male Firewire IEEE connection to female HDMI

I do have a FireWire 800 hook up on the back of my 2010 iMac to to my DVR (Firewire IEEE 1394 input) using a cable like this [https://www.amazon.com/Clear-IEEE-1394-Firewire-Cable/dp/B00699GJW4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00699GJW4) - The one I picked up was a Belkin about 6 years ago. From there I use a program called AVS Browser which automatically reads my DVR. Then I stream through VLC player.

Kind of ticked me off..just a little when I asked an associate at a local computer store this past week of FireWire to HDMI for video, in this smug tone he said - "huh? No such thing, Firewire doesn't work for video, just data" Yeah, 50% true! I wasn't even going to get into it, but yes Firewire WILL work with video connected to a DVR, The video stream is well "data" (NOT all channels on my Fios box works..some network are blocked and will not record. Many do.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions.  If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  See [ask] for more info on how to ask a question.